# Aassigning a value to a view controller from AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, properties, appdelegate

I try to assign a value to a view controller from  **AppDelegate.swift** without success.

My controller is named `DestinationsViewController`, and its id in **Main.storyboard** is `destinationsID`. `DestinationsController` is embed in a Navigation Controller. The objet I want to change is named "label". This is the code:

```
if let destinationsViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("destinationsID") as? DestinationsViewController {
       if let label = destinationsViewController.label{
            label.text = "Super!"
        }
        else{
            println("Not good 2")
        }
    }
    else {
        println("Not good 1")
    }
```

Unfortunately, I get the message: "Not good 2". This is not good :-(

Thank you.

```
import UIKit

class DestinationsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: does your destinationsViewController have a label : UILabel declaration?
How did you add the label? Did you add an IBOutlet?

Comment: Will you please paste the rest of your code that shows how `destinationsViewController` is being added to the view hierarchy?  I fear that you're using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()` to try to reference the existing `DestinationsViewController`.  `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()` will actually create a new `DestinationsViewController` that would have to be programmatically presented.

Comment: To answer your questions this is the code of my DesinationsViewController:

Comment: To answer your questions this is the code of my DesinationsViewController. I added in the top on my post. I dont know how to add here. Yes DestinatonsViewController exists already in my storyboard. I need to set label through AppDelegate.

Comment: You need to describe your controller hierarchy. Is the navigation controller that DestinationsViewController is embedded in the initial view controller in the storyboard?

Comment: I would love to sent a picture of my storyboard, but I dont know how to do it. So there is a Tab Bar Controller, then a Navigation Controller, then DestinationsViewController. The label has been added to DestinationsViewController in the Storyboard.

Comment: I believe destinationsViewController was founded since I got the message Not good2.

Comment: Since the code you posted is in the DestinationsViewController, you can reference your label with self.label. What you're doing is creating a new instance of DestinationsViewController with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier, that's not good.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I should not use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. But how to change label (in DesinationsController) in the AppDelegate?

Comment: Why does the label need to be set from the AppDelegate?  Can it be set in the DestinationsViewController viewDidLoad() instead?  It can be done from the AppDelegate, but it'll be very "hacky".  You would have to get a reference to the TabBarController's child which matches the NavigationController and then get the Navigation Controller's root view controller.

Comment: I will try to explain why I would like to have a label or something like set from AppDelegate. The thing is I want a parser running each time the app is launched. In the begining, I made an instance of the parser in DestinationsController. Every thing was working fine. Except I noticed that the parser was not working every time I open the app in a device. So I created the instance of the parser in the Main Delegate instead. It works fine except now i need to indicate when the parsing in finished in DestinationsController.

Comment: This use case sounds better suited for NSNotifications.  The parser would post a notification when it finished and the DestinationsViewController would have an observer listening for that notification.  When the notification is received, the label gets updated.  However, I've also posted an answer for your original question as well.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here's how you can do it.  However, if you change the structure of your storyboard then this may break.

First, in DestinationsViewController, you need to set a variable that will hold the text because we're setting the text before the view is rendered.  Therefore, the label will not exist yet.  When the view loads, it'll set the label.

```
class DestinationsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
var labelText = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    label.text = labelText
}
```

Now, in the AppDelegate, we set the variable that will set the label when the view loads.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // assuming inital view is tabbar
    let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as UITabBarController
    let tabBarRootViewControllers: Array = tabBarController.viewControllers!

    // assuming first tab bar view is the NavigationController with the DestinationsViewController
    let navView = tabBarRootViewControllers[0] as UINavigationController 
    let destinationsViewController = navView.viewControllers[0] as DestinationsViewController
    destinationsViewController.labelText = "Super!"

    return true
}
```

### EDIT

After re-reading your last comment, I realized you want to set the label at some point after the app has already been running.  You can just move the code in `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool` to where you need it.  Then you can also set the label directly, because the view has been loaded.

```
// assuming inital view is tabbar
let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as UITabBarController
let tabBarRootViewControllers: Array = tabBarController.viewControllers!

// assuming first tab bar view is the NavigationController with the DestinationsViewController
let navView = tabBarRootViewControllers[0] as UINavigationController 
let destinationsViewController = navView.viewControllers[0] as DestinationsViewController

if let label = destinationsViewController.label{
    label.text = "Super DUper!"
}
else{
    println("Not good 2")
}
```

Comment: I need to figure out how to write the lines of code when the parser is done, and it should be done. Can I ask you an opinion? How developer do when they want to parse or do something every time the app is launched? I notice most of the app are not able to update data when the app is launched as for instance is App Store.

Comment: The parser should be running in the background and use a callback or notification for when it's finished.  The callback or notification can then update the UI.  Please look into using [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html).  It's really easy to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good help. I created a delegate for the parser to return a function when the parser is finished, and inside your lines of codes, but still dont work. The function is called correctly but the set is not done. If I place the code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, the set is done. I should probably go into the direction your mentioned, i.e. NSNotificationCenter

Comment: SUPER! Your code works. But to tell the true, I have still the same problem as before : The first time when I launch the app, the label change (initiated to "toto") to the value "Super DUper!". But when I close the app, and try to reopen it, "Super Duper" is still here at starting. Something I still dont understand...

Comment: Is see the problem: How to initiate label to "toto" each time I launch the app because label is well initiated to "Super Duper" after each parsing.

Comment: In the Storyboard, type "toto" in as the text.  It'll be "toto" until it gets set to something else.  The parsing might be happening so quickly, that you don't get to see it display "toto".

Comment: No. After building and running the project with my device connected I got toto for a few sec, then Super DUper!. I then stop the running which stops to app. Then I launch the app through my device directly. It works well the fist time: toto for a few sec then DUper! I close the app, then open it again. I got Duper! not toto.  in fact, i still don't know if the parser is running when I run/stop the app many times.

Comment: Hi, I beleive I posted the wrong question. Thanks a lot for all the answers I got. It helped me to undderstand more. I will probably post another topic since I still can't run the parler every time run the app. It is probably almost nothing I still dont understand.